# ActiveAdmin Edit inputs missing attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

For some reason my "Edit" page for one of my model (chart.rb) is missing on of it's attributes.

Simply adding

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors
    f.inputs
    f.actions
end
```

to the chart.rb file will miss my attribute called `type`.

If I add a special field for type like so

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors
    f.inputs
    inputs 'test' do
      input :type
    end
    f.actions
end
```

It would properly render the type input in a nice format at another section below.

Does anyone know why `f.inputs` might be missing one of my Model attributes?

quick EDIT:
I did a quick patch fix with the following code:

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors
    f.inputs do
      f.input :project
      f.input :name
      f.input :type
      f.input :y_axis
      f.input :y_max
      f.input :y_min
      f.input :x_axis
      f.input :x_max
      f.input :x_min 
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

Which rendered the form just fine. But when trying to save it, I got the following error in Rails:

> The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass:
>   'graph'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved
>   for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this
>   column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance
>   class or overwrite Chart.inheritance_column to use another column for
>   that information.

Looks like the column name `type` is reserved? Is this an ActiveAdmin reservation? Hm.....

Answer (score 4):

`type` is a reserved word for rails.

Here u can see all the [reserved word](http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/)

I recomend you change the column `type` for `kind` or an other word.

---

And you need to add `f.` to `inputs`, like so:

```rb
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors
  f.inputs
  f.inputs 'test' do
    input :type
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: Ah, I think you got it